# How to copy value from one column to another based on conditions in pythons dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe
[image of dataftrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XFX2.png)

I need to copy teleport_value to value column only for cases where row with column **rule** is 'teleport' AND column **value** is '', in other cases the field of column **value** will be without changes.

So, the data frame will be looks like:
[image of requested dataftrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuIpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the conditions on columns as you have described in the question and assign the output to the `value`.
One option is to use `numpy.where` for such cases. Note that there are many other ways to achieve the same goal.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# You don't need this part of the code, I used it to recreate the 
# dataframe, as you have shared a link to a screenshot..
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'operator': np.array([[i] * 3 for i in ['First', 'Second', 'Third']]).flatten(),
    'solution': ['row'] * 9,
    'rule': ['allow', 'block', 'teleport'] * 3,
    'value': [1, 0, '', 0, 1, 'loc', 1, 1, ''],
    'teleport_value': ['', '', 'value'] + [''] * 5 + ['value']
})


# Solution: I have put the comments with your own words from question,
# so that you know what does each line..
df['value'] = np.where(
    (
        (df['rule'] == 'teleport') & # row with column rule is 'teleport' AND
        (df['value'] == '') # column value is ''
    ),
    df['teleport_value'], # copy teleport_value to value column
    df['value'] # in other cases the field of column value will be without changes
)
```